# Search by multiple strings with best result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on indexing some items and am a little stuck on the search functionality after the indexing is done. I want to be able to search my results by the '`name`' column, however, I may not know the exact term, so partial results are needed.

For example, I have entries with the names "`Item entry 1`", "`Item entry 2`", "`item 3`", "`something else`", "`something else duplicate`", "`item entry 1 dup`". And I would like to do a search for "item 1 duplicate".

A `LIKE` syntax won't help here to much. I could do a `LIKE` syntax after each string in the search, however, the results won't be the best. If I use "OR", I will get "`something else duplicate`" on top of "`item 1 dup`". If I do an AND, I won't get anything.

A solution that I have is to do the merges from code. Do a `LIKE` query for each string in the search term, store the results and after that merge them together and sorting them by number of appearances. However, I am wondering if there is something that can be done straight from the SQL query (and is faster).

Thanks

Comment: Google:  "Levenshtein distance mysql".  The only downside is that queries using the Levenshtein metric are slow.

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look over that. Now I at least have where to start :)

Comment: . . If you were using Postgres, I would also suggest an n-gram index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple approach to this problem is:

1. split query string into words by spaces/tabs/other delimiters, like `preg_split('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/')`
2. get unique values `array_unique`
3. construct query string like:

   ```
   select id, count(*)
   from (
       select id from table
       where name like '%WORD1%'
       union all
       select id from table
       where name like '%WORD2%'
       ...
   )
   group by id
   order by 2 desc
   ```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. This seems to get the best results with ease. And is faster than doing everything in Java on each result. Thanks again.